# TFS Rest API, I need users always enter credentials when they using my web application to connect to a TFS collection

Tags: authentication, tfs, oauth, authorization

I have registered a TFS application, I am synchronizing data from TFS to my web application, but I require that when a user clicks on synchronize button the user ALWAYS must enter credentials. Something like prompt parameter = select_account.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your web application and IIS to prompt windows authentication, try to enable Basic Authentication to pass the login information to the server.

Check this case: https://serverfault.com/questions/630590/force-iis-to-prompt-for-credentials